# C# Windows Form App With Ms Access Failed to Insert Data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, oledb

i know this topic is already discuss many time, but i still dont get my problem solved..

ok, i have a form to insert registration data into MS Access Database (2007), but my code doesnt insert data into database, and there are no errors,
here is the code:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = Data/db_klinik.mdb");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(); 


 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

string idCard = this.txtID.Text;
string name = this.txtName.Text;
DateTime dateBirth = this.dateEdit1.DateTime;

cn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into tb_reg (id, name, dateBirth, blood_type) Values(@id,@name,@dateBirth)";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idCard);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);                    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateBirth", dateBirth.ToString());

adapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (result > 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully added");
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("try again");
                    cn.Close();
         }
```

the message box always show "successfully added".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something like this in a project of mine. Maybe it works for you:

```
string insertString = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "INSERT INTO tb_reg VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3})", idCard, name, dateBirth, blood_type); 
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertString, new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = Data/db_klinik.mdb"));
cmd.Connection.Open();

int numberAdded = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (numberAdded < 1)
{
     //do something, the data was not added
}
else
{
     //be happy :)
}
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

As I said, that worked for me.

Comment: hi bema, thx alot it's working, i dont know why but it's working lol

Comment: @Barzul I'm glad you got it working - but please reconsider using string concatenation or formatting to create your SQL statement.  It opens the done for [SQL injection attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx) that could at best expose sensitive data and at worst destroy your database.

Answer (score 0):

The OleDB provider does not support named parameters.  Change your SQL to

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into tb_reg (id, name, dateBirth, blood_type)
                    Values(?,?,?,?)";
```

You can name the parameters when you create them, but it will assign them to the `?` placeholders in the order that they are added to the command.

Also note that you're missing a parameter for `blood_type`.

Whatever you do, DON'T change to use string concatenation.  It open the door for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.